# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've inherited a procedure that is suddenly throwing an error:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small 
ORA-06512: at "BATCH_SERVICES", line 408

In the past, this usually meant that there was a parameter that did could not hold the data it was trying to store/fetch and I have expanded it to varchar2(4000). In this case, however, I'm not sure how to approach this since there is no parameter set in the line that causes the error. Could it be bad data?

Line 408:

```
 xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,1,dr_dash_loc - 1));
```

Source:

```
 create or replace procedure batch_media_services authid current_user as
 --
    cursor balance_upd_cursor is
       select b.ms_billing_key,
              b.ms_bl_balance,
              nvl(sum(j.ms_jb_amt),0) jb_amt_sum
         from ms_billing_dtl b, ms_job_dtl j
        where j.ms_billing_key(+) = b.ms_billing_key and
             (select global_name
                from global_name) = 'DB'
        group by b.ms_billing_key, b.ms_bl_balance;
 --
    cursor job_post_cursor is
       select j.ms_job_num,
              j.ms_jb_desc,
              j.ms_user_id,
              j.ms_jb_trans_date,
              j.ms_jb_amt,
              j.ms_jb_credit_id,
              j.ms_jb_debit_id,
              j.ms_jb_debit_acct,
              j.ms_jb_post_amt,
              j.ms_jb_post_cr,
              j.ms_jb_post_dr,
              case
                 when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CASH' then 0
                 when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CHECK' then 0
                 when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CANCEL' then 0
                 when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'PENDING' then 0
                 else nvl(j.ms_jb_amt,0)
              end right_amt,
              j.ms_jb_credit_id right_cr,
              case j.ms_jb_debit_acct
                 when 'NA' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 when 'CASH' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 when 'CHECK' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 when 'CANCEL' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 when 'PENDING' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 when null then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                 else j.ms_jb_debit_id||'-'||j.ms_jb_debit_acct
              end right_dr,
              nvl(j.ms_jb_post_amt,0) posted_amt,
              j.ms_jb_post_cr posted_cr,
              j.ms_jb_post_dr posted_dr
         from ms_job_dtl j, ms_bill_it_mst
        where ((case
                   when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CASH' then 0
                   when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CHECK' then 0
                   when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'CANCEL' then 0
                   when j.ms_jb_debit_acct = 'PENDING' then 0
                   else nvl(j.ms_jb_amt,0)
                end) <> nvl(ms_jb_post_amt,0) or
               j.ms_jb_post_amt is null or
               j.ms_jb_credit_id <> ms_jb_post_cr or
               trim(ms_jb_post_cr) is null or
               (case j.ms_jb_debit_acct
                   when 'NA' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   when 'CASH' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   when 'CHECK' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   when 'CANCEL' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   when 'PENDING' then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   when null then j.ms_jb_debit_id
                   else j.ms_jb_debit_id||'-'||j.ms_jb_debit_acct
                end) <> ms_jb_post_dr or
               trim(ms_jb_post_dr) is null) and
              ms_bill_it = 'Y' and
             (select global_name
                from global_name) = 'DB'
          for update of ms_jb_post_amt,
                        ms_jb_post_cr,
                        ms_jb_post_dr;
 --
    cursor je_cursor is
       select xmcgurf_batch,
              xmcgurf_batch_file,
              xmcgurf_trans_date,
              xmcgurf_description,
              xmcgurf_amount,
              xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
              xmcgurf_index,
              xmcgurf_account,
              xmcgurf_activity
         from xmcgurf_media_services
        where xmcgurf_trans_type = 'JE'
        order by xmcgurf_batch,
                 xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 xmcgurf_description,
                 xmcgurf_amount,
                 xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind;
 --
    cursor ar_cursor is
       select xmcgurf_batch,
              xmcgurf_batch_file,
              xmcgurf_trans_date,
              xmcgurf_description,
              xmcgurf_amount,
              xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
              xmcgurf_id,
              full_name
         from xmcgurf_media_services,
              mc_person_identification
        where xmcgurf_trans_type = 'AR' and
              id(+) = xmcgurf_id
        order by xmcgurf_batch,
                 xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 xmcgurf_description,
                 xmcgurf_amount,
                 xmcgurf_id;
 --
    balance_upd        balance_upd_cursor%rowtype;
    job_post           job_post_cursor%rowtype;
    gurf               xmcgurf_media_services%rowtype;
    cr_dash_loc        number;
    cr_dash_loc2       number;
    dr_dash_loc        number;
    dr_dash_loc2       number;
    stu_ind            mc_person_identification.current_student_ind%type;
    emp_ind            mc_person_identification.current_employee_ind%type;
    je_date            date;
    ar_date            date;
 --
    je_rep             je_cursor%rowtype;
    ar_rep             ar_cursor%rowtype;
    je_count           number;
    ar_count           number;
 --
    sender             varchar2(100);
    to_list            OWA_UTIL.ident_arr;
    cc_list            OWA_UTIL.ident_arr;
    bcc_list           OWA_UTIL.ident_arr;
    msg_subj           varchar2(100);
    connection         UTL_SMTP.connection;
    line_count         number;
 --
 begin
 --
 -- make sure all balances are correct (for informational purposes only)
 --
    open balance_upd_cursor;
 --
    loop
       fetch balance_upd_cursor into balance_upd;
       exit when balance_upd_cursor%notfound;
 --
       if balance_upd.ms_bl_balance <> balance_upd.jb_amt_sum then
          update ms_billing_dtl
             set ms_bl_balance = balance_upd.jb_amt_sum
           where ms_billing_key = balance_upd.ms_billing_key;
       end if;
 --
    end loop;
 --
    if balance_upd_cursor%isopen then
       close balance_upd_cursor;
    end if;
 --
    gurf.xmcgurf_batch := 'MS'||to_char(sysdate,'yymmdd');
    gurf.xmcgurf_bank := null;
    gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file := 'MS'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmddhh24miss');
    gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date := sysdate;
    gurf.xmcgurf_process_date := null;
    gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code := null;
    gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num := null;
    ar_date := gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date;
 --
 -- Choose job detail entries that need to be posted
 --
    open job_post_cursor;
 --
    loop
       fetch job_post_cursor into job_post;
       exit when job_post_cursor%notfound;
 --
       je_date := job_post.ms_jb_trans_date;
       gurf.xmcgurf_description := substr('Media '||job_post.ms_job_num||
                                          ' '||job_post.ms_user_id||
                                          ' '||job_post.ms_jb_desc,1,35);
       gurf.xmcgurf_ref := substr(job_post.ms_job_num,9,8);
       gurf.xmcgurf_misc := 'MS';
 --
 -- This produces backout entries if the charge was posted
 -- to a wrong account
 --
 -- This is for the job detail charges
 --
       if (job_post.right_cr <> job_post.posted_cr and
           trim(job_post.right_cr) is not null) or
          (job_post.right_dr <> job_post.posted_dr and
           trim(job_post.right_dr) is not null) then
 --
          cr_dash_loc := instr(job_post.posted_cr,'-');
          cr_dash_loc2 := instr(job_post.posted_cr,'-',1,2);
          dr_dash_loc := instr(job_post.posted_dr,'-');
          dr_dash_loc2 := instr(job_post.posted_dr,'-',1,2);
 --
          if dr_dash_loc > 0 then
             gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type := 'JE';
             gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date := je_date;
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := 0 - job_post.posted_amt;
             gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := 'D';
             gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.posted_dr,1,dr_dash_loc - 1));
             if dr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_dr,dr_dash_loc + 1,dr_dash_loc2 - dr_dash_loc - 1));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.posted_dr,dr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
             else
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_dr,dr_dash_loc + 1,6));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
             end if;
             gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := null;
             gurf.xmcgurf_id := null;
 --
             if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
                insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                   (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    xmcgurf_batch,
                    xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    xmcgurf_description,
                    xmcgurf_amount,
                    xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    xmcgurf_ref,
                    xmcgurf_index,
                    xmcgurf_account,
                    xmcgurf_misc,
                    xmcgurf_bank,
                    xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    xmcgurf_process_date,
                    xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    xmcgurf_id,
                    xmcgurf_activity,
                    xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    xmcgurf_seq_num)
                values
                   (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
             end if;
 --
             gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := 'C';
             gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,1,cr_dash_loc - 1));
             if cr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,cr_dash_loc2 - cr_dash_loc - 1));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
             else
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,6));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
             end if;
 --
             if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
                insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                   (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    xmcgurf_batch,
                    xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    xmcgurf_description,
                    xmcgurf_amount,
                    xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    xmcgurf_ref,
                    xmcgurf_index,
                    xmcgurf_account,
                    xmcgurf_misc,
                    xmcgurf_bank,
                    xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    xmcgurf_process_date,
                    xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    xmcgurf_id,
                    xmcgurf_activity,
                    xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    xmcgurf_seq_num)
                values
                   (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
             end if;
 --
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type := 'AR';
             gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date := ar_date;
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := 0 - job_post.posted_amt;
             gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := null;
             gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,1,cr_dash_loc - 1));
             if cr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,cr_dash_loc2 - cr_dash_loc - 1));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
             else
                gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.posted_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,6));
                gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
             end if;
             select max(current_student_ind), max(current_employee_ind)
               into stu_ind, emp_ind
               from mc_person_identification
              where id = trim(job_post.posted_dr);
             if stu_ind = 'U' then
                gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDST';
             elsif stu_ind = 'G' then
                gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDGR';
             elsif emp_ind = 'Y' then
                gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDEM';
             else
                gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDOR';
             end if;
             gurf.xmcgurf_id := trim(job_post.posted_dr);
 --
             if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
                insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                   (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    xmcgurf_batch,
                    xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    xmcgurf_description,
                    xmcgurf_amount,
                    xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    xmcgurf_ref,
                    xmcgurf_index,
                    xmcgurf_account,
                    xmcgurf_misc,
                    xmcgurf_bank,
                    xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    xmcgurf_process_date,
                    xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    xmcgurf_id,
                    xmcgurf_activity,
                    xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    xmcgurf_seq_num)
                values
                   (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                    gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
             end if;
 --
          end if;
 --
       end if;
 --
 -- This produces entries if the charge has not been posted
 -- or if the amount has changed
 --
 -- This is for the job detail charges
 --
       cr_dash_loc := instr(job_post.right_cr,'-');
       cr_dash_loc2 := instr(job_post.right_cr,'-',1,2);
       dr_dash_loc := instr(job_post.right_dr,'-');
       dr_dash_loc2 := instr(job_post.right_dr,'-',1,2);
 --
 --
       if dr_dash_loc > 0 then
          gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type := 'JE';
          gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date := je_date;
          if (job_post.right_cr = job_post.posted_cr or
              trim(job_post.posted_cr) is null) and
             (job_post.right_dr = job_post.posted_dr or
              trim(job_post.posted_dr) is null) then
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := job_post.right_amt - job_post.posted_amt;
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := job_post.right_amt;
          end if;
          gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := 'D';
          gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,1,dr_dash_loc - 1));
          if dr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,dr_dash_loc + 1,dr_dash_loc2 - dr_dash_loc - 1));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,dr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,dr_dash_loc + 1,6));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
          end if;
          gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := null;
          gurf.xmcgurf_id := null;
 --
          if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
             insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 xmcgurf_batch,
                 xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 xmcgurf_description,
                 xmcgurf_amount,
                 xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 xmcgurf_ref,
                 xmcgurf_index,
                 xmcgurf_account,
                 xmcgurf_misc,
                 xmcgurf_bank,
                 xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 xmcgurf_process_date,
                 xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 xmcgurf_id,
                 xmcgurf_activity,
                 xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 xmcgurf_seq_num)
             values
                (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
          end if;
 --
          gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := 'C';
          gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,1,cr_dash_loc - 1));
          if cr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,cr_dash_loc2 - cr_dash_loc - 1));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,6));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
          end if;
 --
          if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
             insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 xmcgurf_batch,
                 xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 xmcgurf_description,
                 xmcgurf_amount,
                 xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 xmcgurf_ref,
                 xmcgurf_index,
                 xmcgurf_account,
                 xmcgurf_misc,
                 xmcgurf_bank,
                 xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 xmcgurf_process_date,
                 xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 xmcgurf_id,
                 xmcgurf_activity,
                 xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 xmcgurf_seq_num)
             values
                (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
          end if;
 --
       else
          gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type := 'AR';
          gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date := ar_date;
          if (job_post.right_cr = job_post.posted_cr or
              trim(job_post.posted_cr) is null) and
             (job_post.right_dr = job_post.posted_dr or
              trim(job_post.posted_dr) is null) then
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := job_post.right_amt - job_post.posted_amt;
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_amount := job_post.right_amt;
          end if;
          gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind := null;
          gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,1,cr_dash_loc - 1));
          if cr_dash_loc2 > 0 then
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,cr_dash_loc2 - cr_dash_loc - 1));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc2 + 1,6));
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_account := trim(substr(job_post.right_cr,cr_dash_loc + 1,6));
             gurf.xmcgurf_activity := null;
          end if;
          select max(current_student_ind), max(current_employee_ind)
            into stu_ind, emp_ind
            from mc_person_identification
           where id = trim(job_post.right_dr) ;
          if stu_ind = 'U' then
             gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDST';
          elsif stu_ind = 'G' then
             gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDGR';
          elsif emp_ind = 'Y' then
             gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDEM';
          else
             gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code := 'FDOR';
          end if;
          gurf.xmcgurf_id := trim(job_post.right_dr);
 --
          if gurf.xmcgurf_amount <> 0 then
             insert into xmcgurf_media_services
                (xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 xmcgurf_batch,
                 xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 xmcgurf_description,
                 xmcgurf_amount,
                 xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 xmcgurf_ref,
                 xmcgurf_index,
                 xmcgurf_account,
                 xmcgurf_misc,
                 xmcgurf_bank,
                 xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 xmcgurf_process_date,
                 xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 xmcgurf_id,
                 xmcgurf_activity,
                 xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 xmcgurf_seq_num)
             values
                (gurf.xmcgurf_trans_type,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_trans_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_description,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_amount,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_dr_cr_ind,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_ref,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_index,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_account,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_misc,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_bank,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_batch_file,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_entry_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_process_date,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_rule_detail_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_id,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_activity,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_doc_code,
                 gurf.xmcgurf_seq_num);
          end if;
 --
       end if;
 --
       update ms_job_dtl
            set ms_jb_post_amt = job_post.right_amt,
                ms_jb_post_cr = job_post.right_cr,
                ms_jb_post_dr = job_post.right_dr
          where current of job_post_cursor;
 --
    end loop;
 --
    if job_post_cursor%isopen then
       close job_post_cursor;
    end if;
```

Comment: Your analysis of the error is the usual one. However, I how on earth do you expect anyone to be able to help with this? We don't have access to any of the data or objects necessary to run this huge amount of code. You need to debug this yourself. Start deleting code until you come up with a minimal amount of code that still errors (i.e. you can't remove anything). If you still can't work it out then provide the object DDL and a _small_ amount of DML to generate the data necessary. Check that this still causes the error. If it doesn't, you've just found it - it's the data, so find it.

Comment: P.S., your procedure is 604 lines long and is missing an end (i.e. won't compile)... no wonder you're having problems working out where the problem is. As part of your debugging consider refactoring it into smaller, logical, units. It'll make your life easier in the longer run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question is actually this:

```
gurf.xmcgurf_index := trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,1,dr_dash_loc - 1));
```

(You left out the `gurf.` part in the version you quote.)

`gurf`, including `xmcgurf_index`, is declared here:

```
gurf               xmcgurf_media_services%rowtype;
```

If you look at the definition of `xmcgurf_media_services.xmcgurf_index`, you will find that it is a `CHAR(...)` or `VARCHAR2(...)` or something, with a specified length; and the problem is that `trim(substr(job_post.right_dr,1,dr_dash_loc - 1))` exceeds that length.

And you do in fact try to put the value of `gurf.xmcgurf_index` into `xmcgurf_media_services.xmcgurf_index` (in `INSERT` statements), so this is not a trivial problem: you have a database column, and a value that doesn't fit in that column, and yet you need to store the value there.

How you solve this problem is a requirements question. I see three likely possibilities:

- Maybe the database column actually needs to support wider values than it does, and you need to widen the column.
- Maybe it's not a big deal if you have to truncate the value to match the width of the column, and lose some text off the end.
- Maybe this column is optional (nullable), and it's O.K. to store null in there if the value doesn't fit.

No one here can help you determine which of these, if any, is correct for your use case.

---

By the way, I recommend you pay heed to the excellent advice in [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458741/ben)'s comments above. You may have inherited this procedure, but now it's yours, and you have to own it. If it's too big and ugly to debug it effectively, then you should strongly consider refactoring it into smaller parts that are better and easier to work with.